# I have working on rasa framework when i have deploying custom action using docker and compose the custome action

Tags: linux, docker, nlp, rasa

I have worked on `rasa framework` using for `AVR chatbot`, I have deploying chatbot using docker which gives the below error:

`sudo docker-compose up -d`

```
WARNING: The DB_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The RASA_X_DEMO_VERSION variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The REDIS_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The JWT_SECRET variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The RABBITMQ_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The RASA_TOKEN variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "rasa-worker": "${RASA_X_PASSWORD:-}"
```

kindly give me better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Download and run the install script on the server:

To install all of the files into the default folder, /etc/rasa, run the following commands:

```
curl -sSL -o install.sh https://storage.googleapis.com/rasa-x-releases/0.29.1/install.sh
sudo bash ./install.sh
```

You will be prompted to accept the terms and conditions. Read the terms, then hit return to continue.

Note
To choose your own installation folder instead of /etc/rasa, set the RASA_HOME environment variable:

```
 curl -sSL -o install.sh https://storage.googleapis.com/rasa-x-releases/0.29.1/install.sh
    export RASA_HOME=~/rasa/dir
    sudo -E bash ./install.sh
```

## -E will preserve the environment variable you set

Replace /etc/rasa with ${RASA_HOME} in further commands.

Start Rasa X:

```
cd /etc/rasa

    sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Set your admin password:

```
cd /etc/rasa
sudo python rasa_x_commands.py create --update admin me <PASSWORD>
```